# HTMLPurifier - having trouble allowing YUI Rich Text Editor styling

Tags: security, yui, htmlpurifier, richtext, rte

I have a simple implementation of the YUI Rich Text Editor, it allows font, font size, bold, underline, italic, strikthrough, background color, text color, ordered and unordered lists, img, and link buttons - but HTMLPurifier in "out of the box" only allows through some of the features.  It allows bold, italics, ordered and unordered lists, and links - none of the other stuff.  Can someone point me in the direction of a configuration for HTMLPurifier that will allow these things and retain the most amount of security I can?  I've tried delving into the documentation but that was - well let's just say it wasn't the most specific documentation in the world.  I had help last night that pointed me to changing magic quotes but that ended up not being the problem.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have magic quotes turned on? What is the HTML being passed to HTML Purifier?